# Where in India do I have the best chance of seeing wild tigers?

Tags: india, nature-and-wildlife

I'm going to India and I'm watching some youtube videos where travellers go into the jungle over an elephant to try to see wild tigers. Most of them didn't see anything. I would like to know which park I have more chances to see them.

Comment: Do keep in mind this may also vary every few years due to varying conditions like drought or poaching.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

India has approximately [39 designated tiger reserves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiger_reserves_of_India) in the country. The most popular ones are Corbett National Park, Periyar, Sundarbans, and Kaziranga for the purposes of "tiger tourism", but I recommend you to look at the list on Wikipedia and narrow down on the ones with "good tiger density" on that page that fits closest to your itinerary.#

The thing to remember that that tigers, after all, are wild animals and they *hate* human contact as it chases away their prey. With increasing levels of tourism, the chances are that these days you're less likely to see a tiger in the wild than, say, 10 years earlier. Nevertheless, the guides at the nature reserves try their best to follow fresh trails - you'll at least get to see tiger trails, if not the actual tigers themselves. It might be disappointing, but it's charming in its own way to be that close. The point is conservation of tiger habitat, after all.

Answer (score -2):

Pench park travel involves tours to the Pench Park tiger reserve. This is one of the major attractions of the [Pench national park tour](http://focuztours.com/destination/pench-national-park-tour.html). The tiger reserve is located on the southern side of the Pench national park. The tiger reserve covers a distance of approximately two hundred and fifty five square kilometers. The tiger reserve center is widely toured among the parks in Madhya Pradesh.  The reserve center extends to the Satpura hill ranges. It is also named after the Pench River that flows through both parks. The park has a monsoon subtropical climate. It has diverse range of flora and fauna. Though the main attraction within the park is the tigers, the forests are also attractive. The Pench tiger park has tropical dry and tropical moist deciduous forests. Some of the trees in the region include the teak and bamboo. They offer great forest shading and a cool breeze. The forested area makes the walks and treks within the Madhya Pradesh national park ideal. The Tiger reserve also has a diverse variety of animals. Among the visible ones, the tiger reserve has tigers, leopards and jungle cats. They have jackals, stripped hyenas and sloth bears. Among the other animals visible in the park include chital, sloth bear and sambar. The park also has wild pigs and wolves. The Tiger park reserve has tigers as the major attractions. They have some species of birds. Some of them include owls and hornbills. The ideal season to tour the park reserve is between the months of June to September.

Comment: Are you involved with the park and/or have you been there?

Comment: after the rollback, it seems that this post is a spam

Comment: It seems a little bit like spam, but it also answers at least partially. Best would be if @alicejoseph elaborates on her/his relation to the pench nationalpark.

Comment: Anyway his answer is a cut&paste: http://focuztours.com/destination/pench-national-park-tour.html